# How To Right-Align an HBoxLayoutContainer Inside a VBoxLayoutContainer

Tags: gxt

I have the following code:

```
    VBoxLayoutContainer container = new VBoxLayoutContainer();
    HBoxLayoutContainer actionContainer = new HBoxLayoutContainer();

    TextButton editButton = new TextButton("edit");
    actionContainer.add(editButton);

    TextButton deleteButton = new TextButton("delete");
    actionContainer.add(deleteButton);

    container.add(actionContainer);
```

Currently, the `actionContainer` is left-aligned inside `container`.  I would like to right-align `actionContainer`, but couldn't get it to work.

How can I right-align `actionContainer` inside `container`?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you want to show the buttons on the right side of the container?

Comment: El Hoss:: Yes, I do

Answer (score 0):

Use `ButtonBar` instead of `HBoxLayoutContainer` and add a `FillToolItem` to the `ButtonBar` as first widget.

```
VBoxLayoutContainer container = new VBoxLayoutContainer();
ButtonBar actionContainer = new ButtonBar();

actionContainer.add(new FillToolItem());

TextButton editButton = new TextButton("edit");
actionContainer.add(editButton);

TextButton deleteButton = new TextButton("delete");
actionContainer.add(deleteButton);

container.add(actionContainer);
```

Hope that helps.